# Remainder of file ignored C:\google_cloud_storage-1.30.0-py3.8-nspkg.pth

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pip, google-cloud-storage, google-api-python-client

I have installed the following google libs:

```
google-api-core                      1.22.1
google-api-python-client             1.10.0
google-auth                          1.20.1
google-auth-httplib2                 0.0.4
google-auth-oauthlib                 0.4.1
google-cloud                         0.34.0
google-cloud-core                    1.4.1
google-cloud-storage                 1.30.0
google-crc32c                        0.1.0
```

To help me store google client credentials. However, I face such error when I download it to my venv.:

```
Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 3 of C:\google_cloud_storage-1.30.0-py3.8-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\python38\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 553, in module_from_spec
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
```

Does anyone know what I shall do?

Comment: Can you show us how you're installing it? What command do you run that generates that error?

Comment: @DustinIngram Thanks for your reply. I am pip installing it if that answers your question. As well as, that error pops out on any command that rusn on the venv. From pip list -l to freeze...

Comment: What version of `pip`?

Comment: pip version 20.1.1. Just updated it to 20.2.2. The error persists regardless.

Comment: Can you show us the commands you used to install those packages? Specifically, how did you install `google-cloud-storage`?

Comment: @DustinIngram Sure! So they were pip install google-cloud-storage & pip install google-cloud from https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-storage/ & https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud/ respectively. If that answers your question.

Comment: Are there other files starting with `google_` in your `C:\` directory?

Comment: @DustinIngram you mean other google libs?

Comment: Yes, at the top like `C:\google_cloud_storage-1.30.0-py3.8-nspkg.pth`

Comment: oh well, `\google_cloud_storage-1.30.0-py3.8-nspkg.pth` is in a folder amongst other files. I just erased the root directories in between. I am not sure where you are trynna get at.

Comment: Ah, that was confusing me. What's the full path to this file?

Answer (score 2):

When having a similar problem related to the package "zope." I did
`pip install -U zope`. And it fixed the problem. See if this works.

I suggest trying

```
pip install -U google-cloud-storage
```